# using fsolve to solve non-linear equations in matlab

Tags: systems-of-equations, matlab, singular-cas

I'm trying to solve this system equations in matlab

```
syms  y z i
x=[29.6,29.4,34.4,35.1,34.3,36.1,31.6,32.9,31.5,28.3,37.1,28.4,27.3,33.1,31.3,33.1]
n = 16
eqns = sym(zeros(1, 2 * n));

for i = 1:n
    a = 0;
    for j = 1:i
        a = a + exp(-((x(j) - y) / z));
    end
    a = i/z - a/z;
    eqns(i) = a == 0;
end

for i = 1:n
    a = 0;
    for j = 1:i
        a = a + ((x(j) - y)/z^2) - ((x(i) - y)/z^2) * exp((-x(j) + y)/z);
    end
    a = -i/z + a;
    eqns(i + 16) = a == 0;
end
eqns
solve(eqns, [y, z])
```

But it seems `solve` can't solve this one.

```
Warning: Cannot find explicit solution. 
> In solve (line 316)
  In xx (line 24)
```

I tried to use fslove but by follow the tutorial at https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

but when I tried to enter

```
function F = root2d(x)

F(1) = exp(-exp(-(x(1)+x(2)))) - x(2)*(1+x(1)^2);
F(2) = x(1)*cos(x(2)) + x(2)*sin(x(1)) - 0.5;
```

matlab throw error.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

P/S: Can this problem be solved with singular?I'm trying to solve this system equations in matlab

Comment: Your `fsolve` code doesn't match the system of 32 equations you're trying to solve symbolically. It's not clear what you're trying to do. I'm also not sure why you're using `i` as a symbolic variable and the re-defining it in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the problem is without being given the error, but:

```
F=@(x) [exp(-exp(-(x(1)+x(2)))) - x(2)*(1+x(1)^2);x(1)*cos(x(2)) + x(2)*sin(x(1)) - 0.5];
x0=[1;1];
fsolve(F,x0)
```

worked for me. You can do this using "function F = ..." syntax, but then you need to write @F in the call to fsolve.